# The Lambert function has two real branches for $x∈[−1/e,0)$: the principal branch $W_0$ and the branch $W_-1$

Tags: lambert-w

I am trying to understand Lambert W function. I am new to this special function. What is the actual meaning of the word two real branches of Lambert W function for any real $x$. How to find the branch point and branch cuts for the Lambert W function. When I used $lambertw(0,1)$ in Matlab i got the real value but for all other branches I got complex values. Actually I couldn't understand that why only these two branches gives real values. Can anyone can explain it clearly?

Comment: Did you look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function ?

Comment: Yes, I have seen that but things are not crystal clear to me. I didn't get the concept of branches, branch cut and branch point w.r.t Lambert W function.

Comment: Euler and Lambert showed that there is no real solution if $x < -\frac 1e$. The main branch is for $ -\frac 1e < x <\infty$, the other branch for $ -\frac 1e < x <0$.

Comment: How the branch cuts of Lambert function are derived?